# Subquery Format Issue

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I am having trouble getting the format correct for a subquery.

One of my queries displays the following:

This involves making calls to three tables (Ind Stats table, that pulls Game Stats, and Teams Name).  As you can see, this query works fine.

What I'm having troubles with is how to pull each player that had a DD in that particular game.  Players is another able within the database.  All I can understand is that I should need a sub-query but sub-queries are not my strong suit.

Here is my code

```
  SELECT * FROM 

        (SELECT game_Date, 
        game_GameID,
        game_SeasonID,
        game_TeamCode,
        teams_Name,
        stats1_GameID,
        Sum(stats1_DD) AS 'TotGameDD'

        FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
        ON 
        teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
        AND
        game_GameID = stats1_GameID

        GROUP BY game_GameID
        HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
        ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc) t

    INNER JOIN  players INNER JOIN stats1 INNER JOIN game 
    ON stats1_GameID = game_GameID
            AND
    sstorm_rawstats1.stats1_PlayerID = sstorm_players.player_PlayerID
```

"

So, to be clear, this works fine:

```
  SELECT game_Date, 
    game_GameID,
    game_SeasonID,
    game_TeamCode,
    teams_Name,
    stats1_GameID,
    Sum(stats1_DD) AS 'TotGameDD'

    FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
    ON 
    teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
    AND
    game_GameID = stats1_GameID

    GROUP BY game_GameID
    HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
    ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc
```

I'm just trying to display the name of the players who recorded a DD in the row here.  I'm getting the name now but it is counting all games that the player played.  I'm close now.

[image]

**UPDATE: I can now display the results in the table but it only shows one player who got a DD.  I'm thinking I need a loop to display all the users who have a DD.  Any help, much appreciated.**

[image]

I just changed my above code by adding a GROUP BY stats1_DD and another AND in the FROM Statement as such:

```
  FROM game INNER JOIN teams INNER JOIN stats1
    ON 
    teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
    AND
    game_GameID = stats1_GameID
    AND
    game_PlayerID = player_PlayerID


    GROUP BY game_GameID, stats1_DD
    HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
    ORDER BY Sum(stats1_DD) desc
```

Comment: what is name of players table and is your players table name consists id based rows?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need here, can you be a little more clear (by say, giving the details of the query that works or something similarly concrete)?

Comment: you should post the original query and the desired results.  it sounds like you just need a join actually, but then you will get repeating rows (per player with DD) - maybe not what you want.  hard to answer as is.

Comment: Please show your schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should join the third table with the result set that coming from the query you already have or with the three table directly on the target column `DD`. Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourCrrentQuery t
INNER JOIN ThePlayersTable p ON p.DD = t.DD;
```

**OR:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourCrrentQuery t
WHERE DD IN (SELECT DD 
             FROM ThePlayersTable 
             WHERE DD IS NOT NULL);
```

---

**Update:** You will need to `JOIN` the subquery with the `Players` table like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
     game_Date, 
     game_GameID,
     game_SeasonID,
     game_TeamCode,
     teams_Name,
     stats1_GameID,
     Sum(stats1_DD) AS 'TotGameDD'
     FROM game 
     INNER JOIN teams 
     INNER JOIN stats1  ON teams_TeamCode = game_TeamCode
                       AND game_GameID    = stats1_GameID
     GROUP BY game_GameID
     HAVING Sum(stats1_DD) >1
) t
INNER JOIN players p ON t.TotGameDD = p.DD
ORDER BY t.TotGameDD desc;
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess it is a little more complicated.  I have to pull the Name of the Players in the Players Table who recorded the DDs in the Ind Stats table for the games with the most DD.  

Now that sentence even sounds confusing to me...

Comment: @kentrenholm - `JOIN` then the way I did then select the name from the players table.

Comment: I tried but did not work.  I've updated my question with our advice

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have this error: Unknown column 'p.DD' in 'on clause'  Looks like it is looking for a DD column in players.  One does not exist.  The DD column is in stats1.